# PHP string echoing with " around strings

Tags: php, string

I have the php function I am trying use,

```
echo get_products_display_price($_GET['products_id']);
```

my out put is "$199.99" with the quotes, is there a way to get it to output with out the " around the string without having to mess much with the function itself something like `substr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php):

```
echo trim(get_products_display_price($_GET['products_id']), "'\" ");
```

It will remove all `"`, `'`and white spaces at the beginning and end of the string.

---

But I am wondering why the quotes are displayed. If you are echoing strings, normally the quotes are not printed as long as they are not part of the strings itself. You should check your `get_products_display_price` function and fix the error there.

Comment: How could I forget `trim()`? +1

Comment: The quotes were/are a result of how Chrome/Chromium outputs the html source. This doesn't occur in other browsers and so I would say this is a solved problem. Should have tried other browsers :D

Answer (score -1):

```
echo str_replace('"','',get_products_display_price($_GET['products_id']));
```

or

```
ereg_replace('"', '', get_products_display_price($_GET['products_id']));
```

Comment: Both your examples will replace all the quotes in a string.